# Add Language store view effect performance badly?

Tags: performance, language

I'm considering to add more language store view

We have over 90,000 sku products. Magento 1.8.1

**Adding another language store view effect any performance badly?**

If so, where and how much effect? front-end or back-end, Search speed, reindex time etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you add affects performance. Unfortunately I cannot tell you how much will be affected.

For example, the reindex will be affected.
Instead of indexing 1 store view it will reindex 2 store view. The time needed is not double because for example the attribute index or category product relation does not depend on the store views, but the catalog flat category and products and the search index depends on the store view.

For frontend the search might be affected but not by much. full text search table there is a column called `store_id` that references the store and I think there is an index on that (but I may be wrong).

Reading the categories and products will not be impacted if you have the flat catalog enabled. Once the index is done you will have a separate table for each store view so no problems there.

I guess the best way to find out is to test and see if the difference in performance affects you much or not.